# How to throw custom error when node-sass compile sass code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, node-sass

I choose node-sass to compile my sass code, but what things can I do when the code is compiling?

In other words, I want make my own rules and throw custom errors in certain condition when compiling.

Comment: Throwing custom errors for what?  Where?  In Sass?  In Node?

Comment: I think they mean node-sass compilation - @cimmanon.

Comment: @mrpeak - you could use [quesadilla](http://www.github.com/seedalpha/quesadilla), it throws a message when you have an error, but if I remember correctly, node-sass is agnostic to error handling - 

will return with code to which solves this

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look for node-sass `(according to 3.x.x)` documentation (on the readme) - it explains how to add your own error messaging via the `error` object when you render.

[render callback](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#render-callback--v300)

[error object](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#error-object).

> from documentation

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
sass.render({
  file: scss_filename,
  [, options..]
}, function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
```

> custom error message

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
sass.render({
  file: scss_filename,
  [, options..]
}, function(err, result) { 
  if (err) throw new Error(err)
});
```